# How to fix undefined variable error in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to running my coding but I got error which is undefined variable.

Here's my controller:

```
$usr_color = DB::table('listbox')
                ->select('lstbx_codename','lstbx_descname')
                ->where('lstbx_cat', '=', 'usr_prf_color')
                ->orderBy('lstbx_no', 'asc')
                ->get();
```

Here's my view:

```
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Color</label>
                                            <select name="usr_prf_color" class="form-control">
                                                @foreach ($usr_color as $color) 
                                                    <option value="{{ $color-> lstbx_codename }}" 
                                                        {{ old('usr_prf_color') == $color-> lstbx_codename ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                                        {{ $color-> lstbx_descname }}
                                                    </option>
                                                @endforeach
    
                                                
                                                --}}
    
                                             </select>
                                        </div>
```

My error is "Undefined variable: usr_color".

Comment: add the specific error and how you are returning the variable from controller to your question.

Comment: are you sure your passing `$usr_color` to you view ? put that code

Comment: Are you returning `$usr_color` in the controller's response?

Comment: yes, I'm returning the $usr_color in the controller also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check that variable before loop

```
@if(!empty($usr_color))

   // you can loop here

@endif
```